# It's calling my pygame invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have used pygame and rect drawing before, but now for some reason it's calling my pygame on line 17 invalid. This is the first time this has happened before. I think I've imported it right, but I'm not sure what else I should be looking for

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.event.get()
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
playercoords_a = (275,425)
playercoords_b = (275,475)
playercoords_c = (225,475)
playercoords_d = (225,425)
playertotalcoords = (playercoords_a, playercoords_b, playercoords_c, playercoords_d)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500),0,32)
windowSurface.fill(black)
xmod = 0
ymod = 0
player = pygame.rect(windowSurface,white,(225 + xmod,425 - ymod,50,50)
pygame.draw.rect(player)
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                xmod -= 25
                windowSurface.fill((black,))
                pygame.draw.rect(player)
                pygame.display.update()
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                xmod += 25
                windowSurface.fill((black,))
                pygame.draw.rect(player)
                pygame.display.update()
            if event.key == K_UP:
                ymod += 25
                windowSurface.fill((black,))
                pygame.draw.rect(player)
                pygame.display.update()
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                ymod -= 25
                windowSurface.fill((black,))
                pygame.draw.rect(player)
                pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if player.colliderect()
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket. I've voted to close as a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've not closed the braces on line before

Can you please Change the lines

```
player = pygame.rect(windowSurface,white,(225 + xmod,425 - ymod,50,50)
pygame.draw.rect(player)
```

To :

```
player = pygame.rect(windowSurface,white,(225 + xmod,425 - ymod,50,50))
pygame.draw.rect(player)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this in the future.